How to avoid this error while deploying next.js app on production getting error of the type<any> due to typescript?
This is the error showing while trying to build the application due to the type any. This error is showing while the building process of next.js app.
I have also used this solution but still not working during the app building process and getting error of type any.

Welcome to SO! Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

I think the error you're encountering is due to declaring some variables as any type, or this might be happening implicitly. You need to verify the variables and assign them correct types. The problem could also stem from using libraries that require loading their types separately. In either case, you can disable the feature that gives this error, although it is not recommended. You can disable this in the tsconfig.json file by adding this property inside the compiler options as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  }
}

